# How do I attached behaviors to a TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf

I know how to attach behaviors to a TreeView, for example:

```
        <TreeView
            x:Name="TestCases"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TestCases}"
            Margin="0, 10, 0, 0">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behavior:TreeViewSelectedItemBlendBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type testCases:TestCase}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSets}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

But is it possible to add a behavior to every Item instead (to make something when "Selected" event is fired)? I don't know where I should put it as I use an ItemSource binding.